# All name servers should resolve to IP addresses

Tags: spam-prevention, spamassassin

when i check my domain for spam

in https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=mydomain.com

i am getting error

**All name servers should resolve to IP addresses.**
Name servers that don't resolve reliably greatly reduce your domain's robustness.
Only one NS IP

how to solve this?

EDIT:

if i am changing name server

ns1.****.com to an ip address will it solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they're asking you to add an `A` record for your `NS` domain. That means, that if you have `ns1.domain.com` which is your `NS` record, it should also have at least an `A` record with an IP address. You can also add an `AAAA` (IPv6) address if you have one, as it's used by systems that already handle IPv6.

Comment: should i add A record for  ns1.domain.com or just domain.com?

Comment: The text says you should add it for your nameserver. So for `ns1.domain.com`. However, your `domain.com` should have one too, in terms of usability.

Comment: Piggybacking as I'm getting the same issue.  But I have an NS record for peidev-vps.peidev.com and an A record for the same with the IP address... still getting the error.